# Ruby on Rails: how do I create an initializer method in the model or should I set all the default params in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model, controller

I have a field in my model for date created, this is not passed from the form and is currently set in the create method of my controller.

Should this be in my model instead in some sort of initializer method? If so what would that method look like?

I have other fields I want to set as a default each a record is created so I'm trying to find out where is the accepted standard place to put these. I'm starting to think it should be the model as if the model was ever called outside the controller it wouldn't have all this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally create builders and never use directly the standard Rails method `create`.

The point is to gather all the logic in one place with particular cases etc...

Basically in controllers I end up calling the builders this way:

```
@my_model_instance = MyModelBuilder.new(current_user, params[:my_model]).build

@my_model_instance = MyModelBuilder.new(current_user, params[:my_model]).create
```

All my builders live in `/app/builders`

---

Here is a very basic example:

```
class MyModelBuilder

  attr_accessor :params, :user, :my_model

  # consider using a Struct if you keep a very basic initializer
  def initialize(user, params)
    self.user = user
    self.params = params
  end

  def build
    my_model
  end

  def create
    my_model.tap{|m| m.save }
  end

  def my_model
    @my_model ||= MyModel.new(default_values.merge(params))
  end

  def default_values
    {
      foo: 'bar'
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi apneadiving, I'm a newb, do you have any resources where i could see what such a builder would look like? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide you with an example. I don't use builders to update objects.

Answer (score 0):

Rails already manages the date of creation and update of your records.

If your model has a `created_at` field or an `updated_at` field they will be filled with the time of creation and update of your model.

You can generate those fields easily in a migration, for instance :

```
create_table :hello do
  t.timestamps
end
```

Now, for default values, you can fill them in the `initialize` method of the model :

```
def initialize(*args)
  self.field = default_value
  super(*args)
end
```

Comment: It's no recommended to override initialize method for ActiveRecord object. You could use the dedicated `after_initialize` hook but it's not a proper way to go.